# How to push array to a multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a array with bill details. I fetched the reciept(doc_no) of that perticular billno in another array.

I want an output as a multi dimensional array, that is in the array it will show bill data with the matching reciept data to that bill.

**Expected output :**

```
bill101: {
    ballance : 100,
    paid : 100,
    date:2018,
    doc_no101:{ 
        // reciept data of matching bill number will come here
    }
    doc_no102:{ 
        // reciept data of matching bill number will come here
    }        
} 

bill102: {        
    ballance : 100,
    paid : 100,
    date:2018,
    doc_no103:{ 
        // reciept data of matching bill number will come here
    }
    doc_no105:{ 
        // reciept data of matching bill number will come here
    }        
}
```

**How I wrote my code**

First I will fetch bill table data and I will store in a array

```
$bill_data=DB::table('bills')
    ->distinct()
    ->select('bill_no','paid','total_amount','ballance','date')
    ->get();
```

Next I will do foreach loop and store it in a separate array. I will repeat  these 2 steps for second query that is reciept data.

Finally I will push these array to a single array. But I am not getting the perfect output

**My code**

```
$bill_data=DB::table('bills')
    ->distinct()
    ->select('bill_no','paid','total_amount','ballance','date')
    ->get();

$finalOutput = [];
$temp = [];

foreach ($bill_data as $b) {
    $dumy = array(
        $b->bill_no=>[ 
           'paid' => $b->paid, 
           'total_amount' => $b->total_amount, 
           'ballance' => $b->ballance, 
           'date' => '222']
    );
    array_push($finalOutput, $dumy);
    $reciept_data=DB::table('reciepts')
        ->where('bill_no', $b->bill_no)
        ->get();

    foreach ($reciept_data as $r) {
        $reciept=array(
            $r->doc_no=>[ 
                'paid' => $r->paid, 
                'ballance' => $r->ballance]
            );

            array_push($temp,$reciept);
    }
    array_push($finalOutput, $temp);
}
```

Comment: What do you get?  How is this code deficient?

Comment: The way you wrote this code is badly unefficient because you are executing select query for each bill to the `reciepts` table. Let's say you got 100 bills from `bills` table. That means that the following `foreach` loop will execute 100 queries to DB. You need to utilize eager loading and chunks.